# Why is the height of my div so large?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/up71qeyk/4/

My `youtubeMain` div is much taller than it needs to be which causes an unnecessary scrollbar. I can't figure out how to get the height of this div only as tall as it needs to be without messing up alignment and aspect ratio of the video. I'm new to flex-boxes.

HTML:

```
<div id="youtubeMain">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/xInh3VhAWs8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#youtubeMain {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

#youtubeMain iframe {
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: height: 100%; ?? So this is 100% of the whole window and the youtube video is just filling this.

Comment: Remove the height:100% on the #youtubeMain

Comment: remove the height: 100% from your iframe [I also set a height+width to your video](http://jsfiddle.net/up71qeyk/9/) - although that may or may not be desired. You could even use vh and vw measurements if you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have defined your html as 100% at the top of your CSS. Try this.

```
html {
    margin: 0;
}
#youtubeMain {
    display: flex;
    height: 600px;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: I guess I should have added that I'd like the sizing to stay dynamic. I think I need to look into vh and vw measurements as jbutler483 pointed out.

Comment: perhaps target just the inner HTML tag as 100%?

Comment: By inner HTML tag do you mean the youtube video div? That shrinks the height of the video.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `height:100%`

```css
html, body {

    margin: 0;
}

*,
*:after,
*::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: url('http://www.telephonewallpaper.com/artwork/a-game-of-clones--boba-fett_original.jpg') no-repeat fixed;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: auto;
}

.floatRight {
    float: right;
}

/*#region Nav Bar */
nav {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7); /* CSS3 */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7); /* Safari, Chrome */
    font: bold 1.2em arial, verdana;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

    nav a {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 15px 25px;
        outline: none;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    }

        nav a:hover,
        nav a:focus {
            outline: none;
        }

/* Brackets */
.navClass a::before,
.navClass a::after {
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
    transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
}

.navClass a::before {
    margin-right: 10px;
    content: '[';
    -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(20px);
    transform: translateX(20px);
}

.navClass a::after {
    margin-left: 10px;
    content: ']';
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-20px);
    transform: translateX(-20px);
}

.navClass a:hover::before,
.navClass a:hover::after,
.navClass a:focus::before,
.navClass a:focus::after {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
    transform: translateX(0px);
}
/*#endregion*/

/*#region Youtube Example */
#youtubeList {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 5%;
}

    #youtubeList img {
        margin: 0 2%;
    }

        #youtubeList img:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

#youtubeMain {
    display: flex;
   
    justify-content: center;
}

    #youtubeMain iframe {
        margin-top: 1em;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
    }
/*#endregion*/
```

```html
<body>
    <nav class="navClass" id="nav">
        <a href="https://reddit.com">Fabrication Parts</a>
        <a href="#">Custom Cages</a>
        <a href="Tools.html">Tools</a>
        <a href="YoutubeExample.html">Badass Vids</a>
        <a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="Home.html" class="floatRight">Home</a>
    </nav>

    <div id="youtubeList">
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/xInh3VhAWs8/mqdefault.jpg" />
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/xInh3VhAWs8/mqdefault.jpg" />
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/xInh3VhAWs8/mqdefault.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div id="youtubeMain">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/xInh3VhAWs8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen />
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height: 100%;`

From

`#youtubeMain {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}`